# How to change IntelliJ code formatting for SQL so that if/begin/end align left

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, is there a way to change the code formatting rules for SQL so that the following snippet:

```
if @someCondition = 1
    begin
        print 'Some Condition is 1'
    end
```

Looks like this:

```
if @someCondition = 1
begin
    print 'Some Condition is 1'
end
```

I think I've clicked and fiddled with most of the Code Style settings for SQL, but I can't seem to find one that will align the begin/end statements with the "if" statement.  I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10154/